# Jquery mobile, rails, collapsibles - extra labels appearing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to display a simple collapsible set from a rails app. It works perfectly the first time, giving me the output below.

[image: Good result]

However, when I go back to the page (via the "Save changes" form submit), additional labels are appearing, and I can't work out why:

[image: Bad result]

My index.html.erb file is as follows:

```
<div data-role="page" data-url="<%= request.path %>">

<div data-role="header">
  <h1> CB </h1>
</div>

<div data-role="content">
  <div data-role="collapsible-set">
    <% @gr.each do |g| %>
      <div id=" <%= g %>" data-role="collapsible">
        <h3> <%= g %> </h3>
        <p>
           <%=form_tag "/checkboxen", method: :get do %>
             <% @gr2.each do |g2| %>
               <%= check_box_tag "#{g}_#{g2}" %>
               <%= label_tag "#{g}_#{g2}",g2 %>
             <% end %>
             <%= submit_tag %>
           <% end %>
        </p>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

While my (very simple) checkboxen_controller.rb is this:

```
class CheckboxenController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @gr=["one","two","three"]
    @gr2=["a","b","c"]
  end
end
```

As you can probably guess, I'm a newbie to this, and can't work out why it's happening (if it matters, I've turned turbolinks off, and have no unusual javascript in the system).

Answer (score 0):

I've found a work-around: instead of using `<%= label_tag %>` I explicitly enclosed the check_box_tag in a `<label> ... </label>`. Why the original didn't work is something I still haven't figured out.